# How to copy an ActiveX control over to another sheet preventing the name change of the control

Tags: vba, excel, activexobject, name-collision

I am using the code below to copy a command button from one sheet and paste it into another:

```
Sheets("SRC").HasACustomName.Copy
Sheets("TRGT").Range("O1").PasteSpecial
```

When I paste it, it get's renamed from `HasACustomName` to `CommandButton1`.

Can I either copy/paste it in a way that retains the name or change the name after pasting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## ActiveX

You can copy an ActiveX Control from one sheet to another with the below code.

Note: *you cannot have two objects of the same name on one spreadsheet.*

```
Sub CopyActiveX()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim x As OLEObject, y As OLEObject
    Set x = Sheets("SRC").OLEObjects("HasCustomName")
    Set y = x.Duplicate
    Dim xName As String
    xName = x.Name
    y.Cut
    With Sheets("TRGT")
        .Paste
        .OLEObjects(.OLEObjects.Count).Name = xName
        .Activate
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

---

## Form Control

To copy a button from one sheet to another preventing the automatic name change use the below code. Excel by default gives a new name to a copied button (*even on a different sheet*) so you have to rename it to match the name of the button youre copying.

Use `CopyButton()` sub to achieve it. There are 4 required parameters

- `from` - sheet name to copy the button from
- `btnName` - the name of the control you want to copy
- `toWorksheet` - target worksheet
- `rng` - target range to associate with the button

---

```
Sub CopyPasteButton()
    CopyButton "SRC", "Button 1", "TRGT", "B10"
End Sub

Private Sub CopyButton(from As String, btnName As String, toWorksheet As String, rng As String)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Sheets(from).Shapes(btnName).Copy
    Sheets(toWorksheet).Activate
    Sheets(toWorksheet).range(rng).Select
    Sheets(toWorksheet).Paste
    Selection.ShapeRange.Name = btnName
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! I've changed to:

Sheets("SRC").Shapes("hasACustomName").Copy
Sheets("TRGT").Range("O1").Select
Sheets("TRGT").Paste

Comment: Nope, after testing I see that this also changes the name of the CommandButton. The caption is unchanged with both the original solution and your solution. But the name changes with both solutions

Comment: @user1283776 ok, I have updated my answer. It copies the button and renames it after. I have debug.printed the name before and after to confirm the are the same

Comment: No downvote mehow! I just returned it to neutral. Wasy that inappropriate?

Selection.ShapeRange.Name = btnName generates an error message "Object doesn't support this property or method".

Comment: what excel version? is it a form control or activex? and you sure haven't modified the code? how many buttons you have on the spreadsheet?  Please see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa223091(v=office.11).aspx) for reference. I have checked the code it does not fail for me.

Comment: My button is an ActiveXControl. You method seems to work for form buttons, but not for ActiveXbuttons.

Comment: I see I wrote form control in the title. Sorry about the confusion and thanks for the help!

Comment: about time I realize that its an ActiveX control. There you go I updated the answer for you

Comment: Thank you very much. But I still can't get it to work. It creates a new button and copies it to a new sheet, but the button loses its name and is renamed into CommandButtonX.

Comment: @user1283776 ok try one more time with the new code in the answer